# How to subset data by group variable keeping all entries in the retained group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to subset a dataframe that looks like

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
           aa=c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,2))
```

I want to retain data on all ids with at least one entry in aa equal to 1. The expected output looks like

```
  id aa
1  1 NA
2  1 NA
3  1  1
4  2  1
5  2 NA
6  2  1
```

I tried

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(aa == 1 )
```

but it's not working as expected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any`

```
df <- df %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      filter(any(aa == 1))

print(df)

     id    aa
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA
2     1    NA
3     1     1
4     2     1
5     2    NA
6     2     1
```